# JQuery & Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble with a modal window type application that I am in the process of building for a page. The applet works perfectly (as I want it to) in every browser, except IE. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the trailing hashtag, or what is happening.

If you view it here http://jsfiddle.net/Qm6Rn/ in Chrome, Safari, or FF, you'll see the way it's supposed to behave. When loading in IE though, as soon as you click the X to close out of the window, and then click on one of the fixed nav elements on the right, the modal animates back into view without any content.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta description="#">
        <meta keywords="#">
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1020" />
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/global.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/global.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=209710702470757";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div id="video_box"> <a href="#" class="close-button">X</a>

            <div class="box-navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#videos" class="sidebar-videos"><img src="http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/video-icon.png" alt="" />Video</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#reviews"><img src="http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/review-icon.png" alt="" />Reviews</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#facebook"><img src="http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/facebook-icon.png" width="18" alt="" />Facebook</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="section video" data-title="videos">
                <object width="640" height="480">
                    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/R9cNtrrCP0E?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
                    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/R9cNtrrCP0E?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="480" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
                </object>
            </div>
            <div class="section active reviews" data-title="reviews">This is a block, and it needs to swap out. Will it work? That is the question...</div>
            <div class="section facebook" data-title="facebook">
                <div class="contentFeedLeft" style="height:480px;">
                    <fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/ceastudyabroad" width="640" height="480" show_faces="false" stream="true" header="false"></fb:like-box>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
            <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
            <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="fixed-navi">
            <li><a href="#videos" class="activator video-button"><img src="http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/video-dark-icon.png" alt="watch a video" />Video</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#reviews" class="activator review-button"><img src="http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/review-dark-icon.png" alt="read our reviews" />Reviews</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#facebook" class="activator facebook-button"><img src="http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/facebook-icon.png" alt="visit us on facebook" class="fb" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $.slidingBox = function (event) {

        $('.fixed-navi li a.activator').live('click', function (event) {

            $('#video_box').animate({
                top: '50%',
                opacity: 1
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 450
            });

            $('.fixed-navi').fadeOut('slow');

        });

        $('.close-button').click(function (event) {
            $('#video_box').animate({
                top: '-50%',
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 450
            });

            $('.fixed-navi').fadeIn('slow');

        });

    }

    $.slidingBox();

    $.slidingBoxContent = function (event) {

        $(window).hashchange(function () {

            var hash = window.location.hash;

            if (hash) {

                var $el = $(".box-navigation ul li a[href='" + hash + "']"),
                    $panel = $("#video_box .section[data-title='" + hash.replace('#', '') + "']");

                $(".box-navigation ul li a.active").removeClass('active');
                $el.addClass('active');

                $("#video_box .section.active").fadeOut(function () {

                    $("#video_box .section.active")
                        .removeClass('active');

                    $panel.fadeIn()
                        .addClass('active');

                });

            }

        });

        $(window).hashchange();

    }

    $.slidingBoxContent();

});
```

CSS:

```
img {
    border: 0 !important;
}
#video_box {
    width: 820px;
    height: 520px;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    top: -90%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -260px;
    margin-left: -410px;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #cecece;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #cecece;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #cecece;
    z-index: 4000;
}
.video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.reviews {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.facebook {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
#video_box .section {
    display: none;
}
#video_box .section.active {
    display: block;
}
.fixed-navi {
    position: fixed;
    top: 213px;
    right: 0;
    color: FFF;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
.fixed-navi li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
.fixed-navi li a {
    background: url(http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/fixed-button.jpg) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 16px;
    font: 10px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #061123;
    border-left: 1px solid #006588;
    border-right: 1px solid #006588;
    border-top: 1px solid #006588;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.fixed-navi li a img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 21px;
    left: 17px;
    width: 17px;
}
.fixed-navi li a img.fb {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 22px;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-bottom: -11px;
}
.fixed-navi li a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -48px;
}
.fixed-navi li a:active {
    background-position: 0 -96px;
}
.close-button, .close-button a {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/close-button.png) no-repeat;
    color: #FFF !Important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #cecece;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #cecece;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #cecece;
    font: bold 26px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.box-navigation {
    width: 140px;
    height: 520px;
    background: #123451;
    float: right;
}
.box-navigation ul {
    background: url(http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/sidebar-button.png) repeat;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 36px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.box-navigation ul li {
    float: right;
    width: 140px;
    height: 38px;
}
.box-navigation ul li a img {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    top: 4px;
}
.box-navigation ul li a {
    padding: 5px 6px 6px 14px;
    background: url(http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/sidebar-button.png) repeat-x;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    width: 120px !Important;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.box-navigation ul li a:hover {
    background: url(http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/sidebar-button.png) 0 -36px;
}
.box-navigation ul li a.active {
    background: url(http://www.gowithcea.com/uploadedImages/js/images/sidebar-button.png) 0 -72px;
    border-top: 1px solid #00638A;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0a223a;
}
```

Comment: I've played with it a bit, and either I'm not using it right, or it isn't working at all. I don't see the X to close out of the window that you are referring to. These are what I see: http://imgur.com/a/793Mo  The top image is when I click on any of the nav links. the bottom image is the same, but when the browser is maximized.

Comment: Console in both IE and Chrome say the "hashchange" method does not exist. Did you properly reference your files?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. If you're referring to the files in the header, those can/should actually be deleted as all of the JS should be in the JSFiddle window. I did a quick copy and paste which is why there are still some files in the header being referenced.

Comment: Charlie, if you expand the browser a bit more you should see the X. Sorry the modal is so large, probably not good for this particular application and request in JSFiddle. It's just to the "northeast" of your screenshot.

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Qm6Rn/3/ to shrink the modal box, and I removed those files not being included. Thanks again for all your guys' help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the version of IE you're using? I tried it in IE9 and the content was still there the second time (just the same as in Chrome and Opera).

Comment: Thanks pimd. I'm using IE 9 but have tried it in all versions (7, 8, 9) and that isn't the case for me. I'm not 100% sure why it's working for you...

Comment: As ridiculous as this may sound, the issue was that I had a # within the anchor tag that was closing the modal window. In doing so, it was appending the URL with the # (naturally) and IE had a hard time interpreting what the hashchange was. 

Sorry to those IE supporters, but that is one more reason why we need to bring IE up to speed. 

Thanks all that assisted in trying to determine what was wrong. 
Jeff